# Difference between sequential criteria for total boundedness (Carothers Lemma 7.3 and Theorem 7.5)

Tags: real-analysis, cauchy-sequences, complete-spaces

Carothers (p. 90-91) includes the following lemma and theorem when describing the sequential criterion for total boundedness. I'm having trouble understanding how they are different. Could someone please explain if possible? (More below).

> **Lemma 7.3** Let $(x_n)$ be a sequence in $(M, d)$ and let $A = \{x_n: n\geq 1\}$ be its range:
>
> (i) If $(x_n)$ is Cauchy then $A$ is totally bounded
>
> (ii) If $A$ is totally bounded then $(x_n)$ has a Cauchy subsequence

Later we have:

> **Theorem 7.5** A set $A$ is totally bounded if and only if every sequence in $A$ has a Cauchy subsequence.

The proof of Theorem 7.5 states that "the forward implication is clear from Lemma 7.3" and then uses the contrapositive to prove that if every sequence in $A$ has a Cauchy subsequence then $A$ is totally bounded.

**Why they look the same to me**: If $A$ is totally bounded then by Lemma 7.3 (ii) an arbitrary sequence in it has a Cauchy subsequence; and if every sequence in $A$ has a Cauchy subsequence, then because the subsequence is also in $A$, by Lemma 7.3 (i), $A$ is totally bounded.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Your last part is not correct. If every sequence in $A$ has a Cauchy subsequence you have proved that $\{x_n: n\geq 1\}$ is totally bounded for any sequence $(x_n)$ in $A$ , not that $A$ itself is totally bounded. Note that $A$ is a countable set in Lemma 7.3 so it does not directly give you total boundedness of $A$ in Theorem 7.5 (because $A$ may be uncountable).

Comment: Thanks! I'm having a hard time imagining a set where any sequence from it is totally bounded but the set isn't? If $A$ is uncountable but all sequences of points in it are totally bounded, then couldn't one simply create a sequence so that, for any $a_n, a_m \in A$ and $p_n, p_m$ in the $\epsilon$-net, $\max\{d(a_n, p_n), d(a_m, p_m)\} < \epsilon/2$ so $d(a_n, a_m) \leq d(a_n, p_n) + d(a_m, p_m)< \epsilon$?